# Ext.Net GridPanel Date Column change default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I use ext.net 2.4 version. There is a date column on the grid and I can change this column. Grid is fill from sql server. My problem is : if the date column is empty (actually the column dont empty, there is default value 01\01\1900 from sql server side) my grid show 01/01/1900 on the grid. I want to grid is show me empty. I did it, when my class fill the grid, I set the column properties Datetime.minvalue. Yes I did the column is empty but I cant change the column, gave me a erorr message.

So if the date 01/01/1900 I dont want to see the date, I want to see empty and ? want to change the empty column. Could you please help me.

my class:

```css
   [Column]
        public DateTime DeliveryDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deliveryDate == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900")
                   ? DateTime.MinValue
                   : this.deliveryDate.Value;
            }

            set { this.deliveryDate = value; }
        }
```

```html
<ext:DateColumn runat="server" Text="Servis Teslim Tarihi" DataIndex="DeliveryDate" Format="dd.MM.yyyy">
                                            <Editor>
                                                <ext:DateField runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                            </Editor>
                                        </ext:DateColumn>
```

Erorr message:

Status Code: 200

> System.Exception: Unexpected token parsing date. Expected String, got Null. at Ext.Net.JSONDateTimeJsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonRea der reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerIntern alReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue) at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerIntern alReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (JsonReader reader, Type objectType) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonRea der reader, Type objectType) at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Stri ng value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) at Ext.Net.JSON.Deserialize(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) at Ext.Net.JSON.Deserialize(String value, Type type, IList`1 converters, IContractResolver resolver) at Ext.Net.JSON.Deserialize(String value, Type type) at Ext.Net.DirectMethod.Invoke(Object target, HttpContext context, ParameterCollection args) at Ext.Net.DirectMethod.Invoke(Object target, ParameterCollection args) at Ext.Net.ResourceManager.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use colum renderer like this,

```
    <ext:DateColumn runat="server" Text="Servis Teslim Tarihi" DataIndex="DeliveryDate"
 Format="dd.MM.yyyy">
     <Renderer Fn="myRenderer" />
    <Editor>
    <ext:DateField runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
     </Editor>
  </ext:DateColumn>
```

and script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myRenderer = function(value, metadata, record) {
       if(value==='01/01/1900')
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sakir, thank you for help. that is work for me. my code last update:

```js
 var BeforeEdit = function (editor, e)
        {
 
            if (DateFormat(e.value) == '01.01.1900') {
                e.value = '';
            }
          
   var DateFormat = function (date)
        {
            var curr_date = date.getDate().toString();
            curr_date = curr_date.length > 1 ? curr_date : '0' + curr_date;

            var curr_month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
            curr_month = curr_month.length > 1 ? curr_month : '0' + curr_month;
            var curr_year = date.getFullYear();

            return curr_date + "." + curr_month
            + "." + curr_year;
        }
   
    var myRenderer = function (value, metadata, record) {
            if (DateFormat(value) == '01.01.1900') {
                return "";
            }
            else
                return DateFormat(value);
        }
```

```html
 <ext:CellEditing ID="CellEditing1" runat="server">
                                        <Listeners>
                                            <BeforeEdit Fn="BeforeEdit"/>
                                            <Edit Fn="edit" />
                                        </Listeners>
                                    </ext:CellEditing>
```